# Optimization problem: combination of values

Tags: optimization

**Problem:**

Given an unlimited amount of empty boxes and a limited amount of items *N*, each with a specific value but not necessarily an unique value. A box has to be filled with at least 1 item and the total value of the items in the box has to be at least a given value *Vmin* to count as a filled box *F*. The value of a filled box minus the minimum value *Vmin* for a box is called the overvalue of a box denoted by *O*. The sum of overvalues of all filled boxes is denoted by *TO*

**Example:**

*Items (N = 5):*

```
Item 1: 1.97
Item 2: 2.32
Item 3: 4.18
Item 4: 6.76
Item 5: 8.05
```

Each box has to be filled with at least 1 item. The total value of items in the box has to be at least 5.00 *(Vmin = 5.00)*.

*Filled boxes: (F = 3)*

```
box 1: item 1 and 3 (box value: 6.15, overvalue O: 1.15)
box 2: item 4 (box value: 6.76, overvalue O: 1.76)
box 3: item 5 (box value: 8.05, overvalue O: 3.05)
```

The maximum possible amount of filled boxes *F* is obviously 3. The total overvalue *TO* is equal to 1.15 + 1.76 + 3.05 = 5.96.

**Question:**

Given a considerably large amount of items. How can one determine the maximum amount of filled boxes *F* while having *TO* as small as possible?